# Capture svn merge output in a variable in Batch script

Tags: svn, batch-file

Following is my code now:

```
@echo off
cd D:\Transversal Unit\example\ace__project\branches\UAT
set "sourceBranchURL=https://coconet-svn-in-01.capgemini.com/svn/repos/transitionportal/branches/BR_TEST"
svn merge -c39,46 --dry-run %sourceBranchURL%' 2>&1 | FINDSTR /I "conflict" > null
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo There were conflicts
cd D:\Transversal Unit\example\script
```

Now here in this merge, I know there is a conflict, but FINDSTR is not working in this case.
The output is blank. Nothing gets printed, it means it is not going inside the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
svn merge -c39,46 --dry-run %sourceBranchURL%' 2>&1 | FINDSTR /I "svn: E" > nul
If %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo There were conflicts
```

Basically, the FINDSTR is looking for the string "`svn: E`" in the output of the `svn merge` command, which I am guessing will identify errors and cause ERRORLEVEL to be set to zero when there are errors.

Comment: This gives some wierd error. The error is mostly because of the 'FINDSTR'. And What is this %ERRORLEVEL%? Is it some environment variable as you didn't SET it anywhere?

Comment: It is an environment variable and FINDSTR sets it according to whether it finds the string you are looking for ("conflict" in this case). Say what the error is please. And edit your question to show the output of the `svn` command.

Comment: Hi Mark, see I have edited my question. Please check and help me

Comment: What is the output from this command `svn merge -c39,46 --dry-run %sourceBranchURL%' 2>&1`

Comment: This command 'svn merge -c39,46 --dry-run %sourceBranchURL%' 2>&1 | FINDSTR /I "conflict" > null' does not give any output. I printed %ERRORLEVEL% it gives 1.

Comment: Ok, and what does the `svn` command output when there is no conflict or error?

Comment: Hi Mark, this command `svn merge -c39,46 --dry-run %sourceBranchURL% 2>&1` is not giving any output.

Comment: Hi Mark, I understood what you are trying to do. But this command `svn merge -c39,46 --dry-run %sourceBranchURL% 2>&1` is not returning any output even incase of any conflicts.

Comment: I understood your question originally said you knew there were conflicts. So how do you know there are conflicts when the `svn` command doesn't output anything either when there are conflicts or when there are not? There must be some difference in output between when there are conflicts and when there are not. I need to know that to help you.

Comment: I have created conflicts manually...hence I know there are conflicts. Using the Tortoise svn GUI also it shows conflicts...but not understanding why this commandline is not working.